# Wordpress logic query

Tags: jquery, database, wordpress, pagination

I return with another round of Wordpress branded migraines. This time I have a more general question...

I have a Wordpress site up and running, all good.
I have a CRM with a SEPARATE database.
I'm pulling data (via PDO) to Wordpress and displaying it.

I don't have the option of merging the databases, and I'm fundamentally trying to pull off a custom SQL query on an external database using the wpdb object.

I've done a lot of digging and appreciate this isn't the preferred route - but I really just need to clarify it's even possible?

So far, I'm pulling data fine but I'm not displaying it through The Loop, nor am I able to paginate (can't figure out how to pass the relevant args outside the wpdb setup).

I hope someone can help - losing my sanity here :(

Comment: Your question it a tad confusing as you ask if it's possible, yet you state you can display the data from the external database, proving it is possible. You will have to code your own method of pagination, As you mentioned you are using the wpdb object to create your custom queries you'd have to post some code to explain that a bit better methinks.

My suggestion is do your own pagination using hidden fields, and/or $_GET/$_POST variables to create links to 'next' and 'prev' pages.

Comment: Hi Gavin, thanks for getting back. I'm indeed displaying the data correctly, but not within a Wordpress object. I was trying to find a way of "pseudo-merging" the databases without an actual physical merger.

NB - after looking into this I've found modifying the wp_query() object directly can allow functionality similar to this, but am I right in thinking this could be a dangerous path to tread?

NBB:  Also I've found a number of the auto-pagination plugins are failing as they simply lay an AJAX layer over pre-existing pagination which I currently don't have in place :(

Comment: I do not think anything should be 'dangerous' per se, as what's the worst that can happen :) Anyways, take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query. From what I can gather it should give you all you need to 'merge' you db to the post.